# Possibility using generic variables in C#

Tags: generics, variables

I have an interface IDatabase that interfaces a few different ways to access a database. For example using RESTful, or MySqlDirectConnect.

Next I have a class foo that has member variables A, B, C that need to pull there data out of the database.

```
public class foo
{
    private string a;
    private int b;
    private int c;
}
```

Originally, I was going to create a Get method for every single member variable. Using Generics, you specify what interface you want to use.

```
public string GetA<T>() where T: IDatabase
{
   //example might be GetA<RESTful>();
}

public int GetB<T>() where T: IDatabase
{
   //example might be GetB<MySQL>();
}
```

and so on....

problem I see is that if the database changes I have to go back and change all these methods. In some cases class foo might have around 20 variables with a Get() method for each.

So I would like to create a really generic GetValue() where I can specify both the interface and the variable i would like to query for.

something along the lines of:

```
public object GetValue<T>(the class variable I want to query) where T: IDatabase
{
    //query database using type T and return it to the variable specified
}
```

I would like to avoid having a conditional for every member variable inside the method.

So is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a great solution I worked out

```
public void GetValue<T>(string property) where T: IDatabase, new()
{
    IDatabase database = new T();
    database.RegisterObserver(this);

    string FROM = typeof(theCurrentClass).Name;
    string SELECT = editProperty = property;
    string WHERE = "1";

    database.Select(new Query(SELECT, FROM, WHERE));        
}

private string fieldName;  //contains the name of the field I want to edit

void IObserver.Update(object data)
{       
    FieldInfo field = this.GetType().GetField(fieldName, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

    if(field != null)
    {
        field.SetValue(this, data);         
    }
}
```

EDIT: I finally figured it out, just updated the above code with the final answer

Answer (score 1):

Generics don't seem like a good fit here at all.  You want an interface `IDatabase` (as you have) which has multiple implementations: `RestfulDb`, `MySqlDb`, etc.

IDatabase can then have a method: `object GetValue(string name)` and you provide the concrete implementation of this in each class derived from `IDatabase`.

If you are using generics then how would your code in `GetValue<T>` know which instance of the MySql database you want to go after -- all it has is a type.

You might want to check out how a project like [NHibernat](http://nhforge.org/wikis/reference2-0en/architecture.aspx)e deals with this.

Comment: would this work? (although I admit its untested)

`public void GetA<T>() where T: IDatabase, new()
{
     IDatabase database = new T();
      a = database.Select(new Query("something1","something2","something3"));
      return a;  
}`

Answer (score 0):

Declare an interface :

```
public interface IDataProvider<T>
{
    T Get()
}
```

then implement one provider per data source and class type

```
public class FootRestProvider : IDataProvider<Foo>
{
    public Foo Get()
    {
        // implement logic to get foos from rest
     }
}

public class FooMySqlProvider : IDataProvider<Foo>
{
    public Foo Get()
    {
        // implement logic to get foos from mysql
    }
}
```

Finally, if properties of Foo come from different sources; merge them in another class :

```
public class FooMerger
{
    // fill this list from constructor
    private IList<IDataProvider<Foo>> providers;

    public Foo Get()
    {
        var foosToMerge = providers.Select( x => x.Get() ).

        // implement merging logic here 
    }
}
```

Comment: it doesnt seem that Select is a valid method for IList, could you elaborate further?

Comment: Select is an extension method declared inside System.Linq namespace : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx